# Try-With-Resources closing multiple input streams in Java?

Tags: java

I have a try-with-resources block:

```
try (InputStream stream = file.getValueAs(InputStream.class); 
    InputStream newstream = 
        new LimitedSizeInputStream(stream, MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES))
{
   // some logic... btw I defined LimitedSizeInputStream class with a close method
}
```

and I'm just wondering if I can change it to

```
try (InputStream newstream = 
        new LimitedSizeInputStream(file.getValueAs(InputStream.class), MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES))
{
   // some logic... btw I defined LimitedSizeInputStream class with a close method
}
```

Will it behave the same way and close both input streams? Or will there be a difference?

Comment: In the second example, the underlying InputStream would be closed iff LimitedSizeInputStream implements AutoCloseable, and then in its close method, called close on the underlying InputStream.

Comment: Or if it extends `FilterInputStream` correctly.